# Problems with SmsBroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, if-statement, sms

First of all, not native english speaker.

I make my .java work with the default code... so it refreshme with the newest sms when they yet come...

But i want to USE them.. something like the following example:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

    if (intentExtras != null) {

                Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                String smsMessageStr = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                    String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);
                    String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

                    String case1 = "@#A";
                    String case2 = "@#*";


                    if(smsBody.matches(case1))
                            {
                                smsMessageStr += "De: " + address + "\n";
                                smsMessageStr += "Este mensaje es generado por el mensaje generico recibido,'@#A'" + "\n";
                            }
                    else if(smsBody.matches(case2))
                        {
                        smsMessageStr += "De: " + address + "\n";
                        smsMessageStr += "Este mensaje es generado por el mensaje generico recibido,'@#*'" + "\n";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        smsMessageStr += "De: " + address + "\n";
                        smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
                    }
                }

                if (MainActivity.active) {
                    MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
                    inst.updateInbox(smsMessageStr);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
```

It is working perfect with the "if(smsBody.matches(case1))" if matches, but if i send a msg with the smsbody == case2, it just give me the "else" statement... making my else if useless...

Some information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are checking if this is true:

```
String case2 = "@#*";
else if(smsBody.matches(case2))
```

The method ***matches*** checks if a string matches a regular expression.

" * " is a special character for regular expressions. I don't know what is smsBody in your case, but probably because of the " * " character, it is making this statement false.

If you just want to see if is exactly the same string I would recommend you use the method equals:

```
else if(smsBody.equals(case2))
```

Comment: Totally correct, that was the mistake, " * " was painted in other colored, but i didn't recall in that... so i keep trying thing with "@# * "... now i changed to "@#B" and is working.. Thanks you! (I voted your comment, but i don't have 15reputation, so.. it won't appear.